# Eliminate contour intersections

Tags: python, python-3.x, geometry, coordinates, contour

I have the coordinates of the points of the objects (x, y). For example,

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point

circle1 = Point(0, 0).buffer(1.5)
circle2 = Point(1, 1).buffer(1.5)
circle3 = Point(-4, 5).buffer(1.5)
```

Some of them overlap. How do I eliminate the intersection so that there is a little space between the figures?
You need to understand that there may be more figures with intersections.
Below I will add an example of what is required:

before:
[image]

after:
[image]

I tried shifting the intersection points to the center of their shape. Also, the idea was to connect the centers of the figures, draw a perpendicular at the center of the intersection and move the points parallel to this line. Unfortunately, I couldn't do it.

Comment: Are they all circles?

Comment: @TimRoberts Not obligatory 
There are figures from several circles to which `union()` was applied. But the basic logic is that everything is built from circles

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
   from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.ops import unary_union


circle1 = Point(0, 0).buffer(1.5)
circle2 = Point(1, 1).buffer(1.5)
circle3 = Point(-4, 5).buffer(1.5)
merged_circles = unary_union([circle1, circle2, circle3])
separated_circles = merged_circles.buffer(-0.5)
print(separated_circles)
```

Comment: The pieces stay together, and I need to separate them

Comment: Code modified @Danila

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite true. You need to make a gap with a small distance between the intersecting objects. You have them combined in your code.

Comment: I have shown this clearly, in the images